Script to change surface mode of all materials from IrayUber to principled bsdf shader (without losing textures connections)
I'm trying to batch change surface type IRayUber to Principled BSDF while preserving texture node connections.
I've tried to use the script from this topic:
Blender - Python Script to batch convert all material surfaces to Principled BSDF
However i had no success, all my materials still show with surface: "IrayUber".

I am not used to python scripting, and still quite new to Blender.
Maybe I missed something in the code or perhaps its just a small change to get it working?
Any help would be really appreciated.
Here is the node tree of a example material.


Hello, could you post an image of the node tree corresponding to this material ? Go to the shader editor to see it while the material is selected

Hi Gorgious, thanks for your comment. I just added an image of the note tree above.,
